# How to find specific driver

Tags: drivers

I need to find a driver for my Hi-Gain Wireless-N Network USB adapter. How or where can I find that? I have tried searching for it myself but to no avail.

Comment: The drivers are generally in the kernel. You need to identify the chip in your wireless. usb. post the output of `lshw -C network`